# Unable to load page using Express from local machine

Tags: webserver, lan

Im developing a webpage using Express framework in ubuntu. The machine I am developing on can access the webpage just fine at `192.168.1.37:3000` or `localhost:3000`, but I can't get other machines on the local network to see the page using the local ip adress. Looking at the headers, it seems that no response is received from the web server.

output from `sudo netstat -tulpn` regarding node.js:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3934/node
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update:
I just enabled port forwarding on my router (port 3000) to my development machine, and I can now access the website at `http://external.ip.adress:3000`, but the local machines still cannot acces the page through the local ip adress. I'm confused :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am abandoning this issue. All steps followed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213175).